# watching the TV?

Tags: definite-article

The following is from a dictionary. Do you think the definite article is correctly used?

He gets all his knowledge about politics from **watching the television**.

If it not, why is it common to say "listen to the radio," with the definite article included?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The difference is whether the context refers to an electric device (a radio, a television) or a broadcast medium (radio, television). To make this easier to explain, you might add some sentence examples. Your example could be either "watching the television set" (article) vs. "watching the television program" (no article).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit weird, but the definite article is optional in your example. You can say it or not. It's less common to use the definite article with "TV" than with "television," but it's almost always used with radio. My only guess about "why" is that television and TV feel more like proper nouns in English, for some reason—like the difference between saying "I am going to go out with **a** friend" and "I'm going to go out with Amy."